# async/await keywords not available in .net 4.0

Tags: c#, async-await

I would like to use the async/await in C# 4.0 and I have installed the following package:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/

The problem is that I do not have async/await keywords available.

I am using VS2010 with SP1.

Thanks.

Comment: Those keywords are new in C# 5.0.

Comment: Why have you created a new question for this? I've already explained what the problem is: Visual Studio needs to know about this at a language level. VS2010 only supports C# 4, not C# 5. Either you need to install the old CTP (a bad idea IMO) or use Visual Studio 2012 or 2013.

Comment: possible duplicate of [which library (which difference) to can use async in .net 4.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421878/which-library-which-difference-to-can-use-async-in-net-4-0)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're not going to get a better answer than [Jon Skeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19421907/263693).

The only supported way to do this is to use **VS2012** with `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`.

VS2010 is very difficult to get working with `async`/`await`. There was an old Async CTP package (which had many bugs that were never fixed) that acted as an "add-on"/"partial replacement" to VS2010. However, that package never worked well with the VS2010 updates. So, you'd have to first find a version of one of the old CTP installers, play around with installing *some* VS updates, and then see if the CTP works. If you've already installed all your VS2010 updates then no version of the CTP will work. I *think* once you find an update situation where you can install a working CTP, *then* you can install the other updates.

After all this work, you'll still end up with a bug-ridden (and definitely unoptimized) implementation of `async`.

**Or**, you can do as Jon Skeet suggested and download the free version of VS2012 Express with `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` and have a fully supported solution.

Answer (score 20):

`Async/Await` have been introduced with `C# 5.0` and `.NET Framework 4.5`

more information here:

[Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)

[Asynchronous Programming in C# 5.0 using async and await](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/591586/Asynchronous-Programming-in-Csharp-5-0-using-async)

If you are using **Framework 4** as I do in enterprise you can use other workarounds.
You can use a NuGet package that allows you to use these features.

[Using async/await without .NET Framework 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx)

Just install it from NuGet package manager:

> Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async

Extracted from [NuGet Gallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/):

> This package enables Visual Studio 2012 projects to use the new 'async' and 'await' keywords. This package also includes Task-based extension methods that allow using some of the existing asynchronous APIs with the new language keywords. Windows Phone Silverlight 8 projects can use this package to get access to async extension methods for the networking types.

Answer (score 5):

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

private void simpleMethod()
{
    var tsk = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWorkAsync());
    Task.WaitAll(tsk);
    DataTable table = tsk.Result;
}
```

It is important that the asynchronous method should not contain any method that affects form controls

```
    private DataTable DoSomeWorkAsync()
    {           
        System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
        Thread.Sleep(4000); // Any long time process
        return table;
    }
```

More information: https://www.simplethread.com/net-40-and-systemthreadingtasks/

Comment: Although this post has been downvoted multiple times, it does show a reasonably valid way of awaiting tasks to complete in this first example, especially for .NET 4.0 as requested by the threads user.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a .NET 4.5 plugin using `async` for a .NET 4.0 application, and to my surprise this actually worked!

I think this worked because I have .NET 4.5 installed, which replaced the .NET 4 runtime with an updated one, which is used both for .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5. Then my plugin was loaded with reflection using `Assembly.Load(...)` or similar. I tried both `async/await` and `Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId` (a .NET 4.5 property), and both worked.

Thus if installing .NET 4.5 is an option (i.e. not supporting Windows XP) one could possibly use a mix by loading the .NET 4.5 part of an application via reflection, possibly letting your 4.5 part implement a 4.0 interface. However, if you are writing the application yourself, then a much simpler solution would be to switch to .NET 4.5 for the whole project.