# How to check every 2 minutes for report checking in datagrid wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, windows-services, wpfdatagrid

I want to check all the datas in database for the status is changed to "Reported" automatically refresh it in wpf datagrid

Here the below code am using,stell me how to given this in a thread for automatically refresh every 2minutes.
how to give the below code for automatic refresh checking:-

```
 public void automaticreport(object m)
    {            
        foreach (var autsdyid in LoadStudyIdentifiers())
        {
            if (!this.reportchk)
            {
                Reportnew cf = new Reportnew();
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((WaitCallback)(o => cf.ReportRetrive(this, autsdyid, true)));
            }
            else
            {
                int num = (int)System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Reports checking in progress, Please wait sometime and try again later", "OPTICS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            }
        }
    }

    private string[] LoadStudyIdentifiers()
    {
        var results = new List<string>();
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            con.Open();
            var autoquery = "Select StudyUID From StudyTable Where status='2'";

            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(autoquery, con))
            {
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    results.Add(rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("StudyUID")));
                }
            }

        }

        return results.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: I think it's too broad to explain in SO context

Comment: @KcDoD:How to given it in automatic thread refresh?

Comment: Is this the code you need to run every 2 mins or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: one option is to use timers.. and trigger some event with timer..

Comment: Yes this is the code,how to given in a thread via automatically -@ThomasLindvall

Comment: @KcDoD :How it possible?

Comment: What framework are you using (I.E C# 4 or later or earlier?)? @NvadeepKumar

Comment: @Thomas Lindvall Am using .Netframework4.0 c#

Comment: To execute thing periodically, you use timers. Please research timers (in WPF, `DispatcherTImer` is a good choice), see how it would apply to your code, and then post a _specific_ question if and when you have problems with that.

Comment: @PeterDuniho :am used the below code,but its not workingprivate void threadtimer()
{
  MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
  System.Threading.TimerCallback TimerDelegate = new System.Threading.TimerCallback(automaticreport);
  System.Threading.Timer TimerItem = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerDelegate, mw, 0, 10000);
   mw.TimerReference = TimerItem;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get the data programmatically I would do something like this:

```
async void Main()
{
    Foo f = new Foo();
    Task s = await f.Bar(); 
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
    }
    //recursive tail function
    public async Task<Task> Bar()
    {
        //enter your code here
        doSomething();
        //Change this to what time you desire
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return Bar();
    }
}
```

You could also run it as a synchronous function with a simple tail recursion it will lock up resources though, you have to take in consideration that this might cause problems if you don't flush streams and dispose of different types objects correctly.

**The safer route:**

My other idea would be to schedule (Scheduled Task) a small worker that collects the data and saves it down to a document (json, csv, xml w/e) and then send a call to your app to update.

Comment: You can add the code where it says doSomething(), you'll need to use VS 2012 though, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423251/in-net-4-0-i-have-not-avaliable-the-async-await-keywords or make it a synchronous task in a new thread. Would recommend that you try this out and see what it does.