# REST service call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, async-await

I have to call method using REST service as I got some solution from material but getting error in `await`

```
public static Task RunAsync()
{
    string pathValue = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["R2G2APIUrl"];
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(pathValue);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var id = "12421";
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
        var jobid = new Jobs() { Job_ID = id};
        response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/products", jobid);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Uri gizmoUrl = response.Headers.Location;
        }
    }
}
static void Main()
{
    RunAsync().Wait();
}
```

await is not exist in current context as I am using vs2010 but is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Doesnt the method must be declared as async?

Comment: @SílvioN. then I get an err of `the type or namespace async could not be found` in async

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19426866/1660709

Comment: VS2010 doesn't supports/understand async-await. You need Vs2012 or later to make it work

Comment: Use `WebClient` instead.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Still the challenge is how to use async/await there

Comment: @SriramSakthivel He can't use async-await with VS2010. That makes it an impossible challange ;P. He can use `ContinueWith` instead.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov can u give me example with continuewith ?

Comment: @debin Why are you issuing a `GetAsync` request but then overriding the `response` immediately with `PostAsJsonAsync`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `await`, you can use `ContinueWith`.

```
public static Task RunAsync()
{
    string pathValue = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["R2G2APIUrl"];
    var client = new HttpClient()
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(pathValue);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var id = "12421";
        return client.GetAsync("api/products/1").ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        var jobid = new Jobs() { Job_ID = id };
        return client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/products", jobid)
       .ContinueWith(responseTask =>
        {
          var gizmoUrl = responseTask.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode ?
                                        responseTask.Result.Headers.Location : null;
        });
    });
}
```

Note you have some redundancies in your code, like issuing a `GetAsync` request and doing nothing with the returned `HttpResponseMessage`.

Comment: m gettin error `Cannot access a disposed object.Object name: 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'.`

Comment: @debin You're right, I forgot to remove the `using` statement. Fixed it now.

Comment: ah thnku so muchh..a little doubt..i will call this method as `RunAsync().Wait()` right? now I want to call a particular method which is in that `pathvalue`..any idea?

Comment: @debin Sorry, I didn't understand your question. What is `pathvalue`?

Comment: I am fetching URL from webconfig that is `pathvalue`

Comment: @debin Ok, and what problem have you encountered?

Comment: sorry m gettin err again of `responseTask.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode 'responseTask.Result' threw an exception of type 'System.AggregateException` I know its certificate related..but how to solve it??i dn want to export certificate

Comment: What is the inner exception?

Comment: the error is `{"An error occurred while sending the request."} and {"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."}`

Comment: yah got it..jus last question..what this method will return??? because m calling it like `public bool restfunc(string id)    {         RunAsync(id).Wait();
 return true; }`so how to save the result or check what is the return value?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just use the .Result of the async operation.

```
     public static Task RunAsync()
     {
        string pathValue = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["R2G2APIUrl"];
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(pathValue);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var id = "12421";
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/products/1").Result;
            var jobid = new Jobs() { Job_ID = id };
            response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/products", jobid).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Uri gizmoUrl = response.Headers.Location;
            }
        }
    }
```