# Task<> does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' in Net Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, api

I am trying to access Web API in C# Code. I have tried below code in .Net Framework 4.0 but its shows an error message as “task httpresponsemessage does not contain a definition for getawaiter”.Please check below code and advise how to resolve this issue.

Code:-

```
static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            
            // HTTP GET
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", product.Name, product.Price, product.Category);
            }

            // HTTP POST
            var gizmo = new Product() { Name = "Gizmo", Price = 100, Category = "Widget" };
            response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/products", gizmo);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Uri gizmoUrl = response.Headers.Location;

                // HTTP PUT
                gizmo.Price = 80;   // Update price
                response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(gizmoUrl, gizmo);

                // HTTP DELETE
                response = await client.DeleteAsync(gizmoUrl);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what line number is the error

Comment: // HTTP GET
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");

Comment: Are you trying to use `System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions`? You should be using `Newtonsoft.Json` and `System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions` nuget package.

Comment: To Michael Randall's point, `GetAwaiter` was [introduced in .NET 4.5](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Threading.Tasks.Task%3CTResult%3E.GetAwaiter()).

Comment: Can you advise what is the alternate solution to access web api in C# using .Net Framework 4.0 ??

Comment: Don't use async/await. Is there a reason you can't upgrade to 4.5?

Comment: ok noted but what is the alternate solution to do in .net framework 4.0,if possible provide me example code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423251/async-await-keywords-not-available-in-net-4-0  If there's an alternative, it's there, and all I had to do was Google ".net 4.0 async".

Answer (score 0):

> ok noted but what is the alternate solution to do in .net framework 4.0, if possible provide me example code

We can make use of the `HttpWebRequest` class available in System.Net namespace.
Along with that Newtonsoft.Json library (available as a nuget package) is also required for serialization and deserialization of data.

Inline is a rewrite of the requirement with `HttpWebRequest`

```
static void Run()
{
    // HTTP GET
    var getRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:9000/api/products/1") as HttpWebRequest;
    getRequest.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
    getRequest.Method = "GET";

    HttpWebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    if (getResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Stream responseStream = getResponse.GetResponseStream();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
                    
            var product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(sr.ReadToEnd());
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", product.Name, product.Price, product.Category);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(getResponse.StatusDescription);
    }

    // HTTP POST
    var gizmo = new Product() { Name = "Gizmo", Price = 100, Category = "Widget" };
    var postRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:9000/api/products") as HttpWebRequest;
    postRequest.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
    postRequest.Method = "POST";

    Stream stream = postRequest.GetRequestStream();
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gizmo));
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    HttpWebResponse postResponse = postRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    if (postResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        //HTTP PUT
        string gizmoUrl = postResponse.Headers["Location"];
        var putRequest = WebRequest.Create(gizmoUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        putRequest.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
        putRequest.Method = "PUT";

        gizmo.Price = 80; //Update price

        Stream putRequestStream = putRequest.GetRequestStream();
        byte[] putRequestBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gizmo));
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        HttpWebResponse putResponse = putRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        //HTTP DELETE
        var deleteRequest = WebRequest.Create(gizmoUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        deleteRequest.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
        deleteRequest.Method = "DELETE";
        HttpWebResponse deleteResponse = deleteRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(postResponse.StatusDescription);
    }
}
```

Note: I have not tested the code from my end. There might be minor modification required if things do not work as intended. However the motive is to provide an insight into `HttpWebRequest` class which can full fill your requirement in .Net 4