# Working with multiple http request-response

Tags: c#, xml, multithreading, http, .net-4.0

I have a program which loops through an apps list.

```
Apps
--------
App1
App2
App3
```

Now, for each of them, I do a http request to get a list of builds for each app as an Xml.

So a request like,

```
http://example.com/getapplist.do?appid=App1
```

gives me a response like,

```
<appid name="App1">
  <buildid BldName="Bld3" Status="Not Ready"></buildid> 
  <buildid BldName="Bld2" Status="Ready"></buildid>
  <buildid BldName="Bld1" Status="Ready"></buildid>
</appid>
```

Now I get the **Highest build number** with **Status "Ready"** and then do another web api call like,

```
http://example.com/getapplist.do?appid=App1&bldid=Bld2
```

This gives me a response like,

```
 <buildinfo appid="App1" buildid="Bld2" value="someinfo"></build>
```

I feed these into internal data tables. But now, this program takes a painfully long time to complete (3 hours), since I have close to 2000 appids and there are 2 Web requests for each id. I tried sorting this issue using a **BackgroundWorker** as specified [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/478485/Multi-Threaded-WebScraping-in-Csharp). I thought of collating all info from http responses into a single XML and then using that XML for further processing. This throws the error,

> file being used by another process

So my code looks like,

```
if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < appList.Count; i++)
    { 
        BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;  
        bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;                     
        bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_DoWork);                   
        bgw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgw_ProgressChanged);
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        //Start The Worker 
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

And the `DoWork` function picks the tag values and puts it into an XML.

What is the best way I can get the app- buildinfo details into a common file from all the http responses from all the background workers?

Comment: This generates 2000 backgroundworkers...not good...instead call your webapi async from one backgroundworker...and use a lock when one of the async webrequest completed events fires and writes to the xml file.

Comment: Could you please add your `DoWork` method code?

Comment: @rene , So what is the limit I have to set it to? Also, If I set a limit of say 5 Background workers, does that mean the threads would run in parallel until all 2K urls are worked on?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov . In my DoWork, currently, I have some code to build a string from the XML response i get and then do a simple  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename,stringvalue)

Comment: try [Parallel.For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx) which is much simpler, and don't have to worry about the performance degradation with too many threads.

Comment: @bansi is it .net 4.0 compatible?

Comment: @bansi No reason to use `Parallel.ForEach` with IO bound work.

Answer (score 4):

HTTP requests are IO bound and asynchronous by nature, there is no reason to use background workers to accomplish what you need.

You can take advantage of `async-await` which is compatible in .NET 4 via [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) and [`HttpClient`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http):

```
private async Task ProcessAppsAsync(List<string> appList)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    // This will execute your IO requests concurrently,
    // no need for extra threads.
    var appListTasks = appList.Select(app => httpClient.GetAsync(app.Url)).ToList();

    // Wait asynchronously for all of them to finish
    await Task.WhenAll(appListTasks);

   // process each Task.Result and aggregate them to an xml
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"PathToFile")
    {
        foreach (var appList in appListTasks)
        {
           await streamWriter.WriteAsync(appList.Result);
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you process all requests concurrently and handle results from all of them once they've completed.

Comment: @rene The OP can write synchronously if needed after `Task.WhenAll`, although i see no reason for him to do that.

Comment: @mhn I added code writing asynchronously to a file using `StreamWriter`, if needed.

Comment: Inspite of adding Microsoft.Bcl.Async and HttpClient, as you suggested, i get the "Type or namespace async could not be found " error . any pointers?

Comment: happened to stumble upon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421878/how-can-i-use-the-async-keywords-in-a-project-targetting-net-4-0/19421907#19421907 . But i do not have VS 2012 installed :(

Comment: You can download VS2012 express, which is free.

Comment: I can try this on my local machine. But the working code would be a step in an SSIS Script component on another Server Machine and I do not have permissions to install there. So is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for .Net 2.0 and up by using the async methods from the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.80).aspx) class and using a counter that is decremented with the [Interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.decrement(v=vs.110).aspx) class and ordinary [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx#Y370) to serialize the writing of the results to the file.

```
var writer = XmlWriter.Create(
    new FileStream("api.xml",
                    FileMode.Create));
writer.WriteStartElement("apps"); // root element in the xml
// lock for one write
object writeLock = new object(); 
// this many calls            
int counter = appList.Count;

foreach (var app in appList)
{
    var wc = new WebClient();

    var url = String.Format(
        "http://example.com/getapplist.do?appid={0}&bldid=Bld2", 
        app);
    wc.DownloadDataCompleted += (o, args) =>
        {
            try
            {
                var xd = new XmlDocument();
                xd.LoadXml(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(args.Result));
                lock (writeLock)
                {
                    xd.WriteContentTo(writer);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // count down our counter in a thread safe manner
                if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref counter) == 0)
                {
                    // this was the last one, close nicely
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.Close();
                    ((IDisposable) writer).Dispose();
                }
            }
        };
    wc.DownloadDataAsync(
        new Uri(url));   
}
```

Comment: Do you really see a benefit in making so many synchronous writes to a file instead of aggregating the results and writing once, leaving out lock contention at all?

Comment: I'm not sure for this case but if the results are large enough memory might be an issue. Or in case of failure and it is expensive to re-run you would have intermediate results (but that would require restart-logic). I'm more concerned about the possibility of having that many network connections open.

Comment: He can always throttle requests if needed. He can also process them as they finish using `Task.WhenAny`.