# C#, execute a method after x seconds, from background

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

Is it possible to execute a method after 30 second from background on click event(no regular event)?  By "from background" I mean that UI is still working; there's no active waiting. I can't use `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x)` and so on.

I tried `Timer` Class, but I can't get it working how I want.

Comment: Why can't you use a `Thread`? Unclear to me.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at the `Task` or `BackgroundWorker` class

Comment: How, specifically, is your timer solution not working, and what code are you using.

Comment: @sloth: You'd still need `Thread.Sleep` or `Task.Delay`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Sure. But how is that a problem?

Comment: @sloth: OP says he can't use them. (Actually I don't know...)

Comment: @PatrickHofman He says no such thing, although creating a new thread just so that it can do nothing but sit around waiting for several seconds is extremely wasteful.  An asynchronous solution, such as using a `Timer`, is noticeably preferable.

Comment: @Servy: Okay. I guess I just misread then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the button click event handler `async`, and then just delay the task for the time you need:

```
private async void YourButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    // do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Just adding that this is a C# 5.0 feature.

Comment: Then update to use .NET 4.5. That is your best option. Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19421878/993547) to get support on .NET 4.0.

Comment: Do I need to upgrade Visual Studio, now I'm using 2010 Express, or only .NET framwork? Thanks

Comment: I would recommend to upgrade since VS 2015 is coming soon already. You can download the VS 2013 community edition for free.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to change target version of .NET in VS2013. Everything works fine.